# Eclipse Oxygen - Run configuration: Classpath settings

Tags: java, eclipse

I have added http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ library to classpath and when I try to run I got [image: ClassNotFoundException]

I tried using other classes from library and they all got me `ClassNotFoundException`.
Can anyone point me to my mistake?

P.S. I tried to re-download library and looked few guides - they all tell that simply "Build path" -> "Add to Build path" should be sufficient.

Comment: Check whether your eclipse has installed JDK/JRE or not whatever version of jdk  you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **Apache Commons Lang 3** to your Classpath Entries

you can find it here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0

then 
1) "Add External jar" into the classpath entries
2) Clean and build the project again

Answer (score 1):

The error says that a class in the opencsv package (`com.opencsv.CSVParserBuilder`) failed to load a class from Apache Commons (`ObjectUtils`)

Per http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html, opencsv itself is indeed dependent on a few Apache libraries. These are not included in opencsv's JAR and you need to add them to your project classpath.

Comment: Thanks, I got that problem was in dependencies of OpenCSV.